# Update one table with data from 3 other tables where id = id and location = location

Tags: mysql

Using mysql (phpmyadmin) I am trying to figure out how to update table1 with data from table 2, table3, table4 if the UniqueID and LocationNum both match. I can easily get one table to populate table1 but i am stuck on adding the rest with the (WHERE UniqueID = UniqueID and LocationNum =  LocationNum;) part. Please help me out

table1 (trying to fill this with data from all other tables)
UniqueID, LatDec, LongDec, LocationNum, AntennaNum, FrequencyAssigned, Azimuth, EIRP, PolarizationCode, Gain

table2
UniqueID, AntennaNum, LocationNum, PolarizationCode, Gain, Azimuth, LineLoss

table3
UniqueID, LocationNum, AntennaNum, FrequencyAssigned

table4
UniqueID, LocationNum, LatDec, LongDec

Comment: Have you took a look at MySQL Joins?

Comment: I have but all that I have tried have failed

Comment: Just tell us what you have tried

Comment: SELECT 
    table2.UniqueID, table2.LocationNum, table2.FrequencyAssigned
FROM
    table2
INNER JOIN 
    table1 ON table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID and table1.LocationNum = table2.LocationNum;

Comment: UPDATE
    table1
    SET
    table1.FrequencyAssigned = table2.FrequencyAssigned
WHERE
    table1.UniqueID = table2.UniqueID and table1.LocationNum = table2.LocationNum;

Comment: Why are you trying to put all the data in one table? What is the problem it solves?

Comment: I need table1 to have UniqueID, LatDec, LongDec, LocationNum, AntennaNum, FrequencyAssigned, Azimuth, EIRP, PolarizationCode, Gain filled by the other tables if the uniqueID and the LocationNum match.

Comment: UPDATE table1 (Azimuth, PolarizationCode)
SELECT Azimuth, PolarizationCode
FROM table2
WHERE UniqueID = UniqueID and AntennaNum =  AntennaNum;

Comment: SET INTO table1 (Azimuth, PolarizationCode)
SELECT Azimuth, PolarizationCode
FROM table2
WHERE UniqueID = UniqueID and AntennaNum =  AntennaNum;

Comment: REPLACE INTO table1 (Azimuth, PolarizationCode)
SELECT Azimuth, PolarizationCode
FROM table2
WHERE UniqueID = UniqueID and AntennaNum =  AntennaNum;

Comment: I have tried those things

Comment: I need all the data on one table because that is the table I use to search for records and would need to only search one table rather than 3. the data I get to put into the tables comes from multiple sources and cannot be put into one table when I put it into the database.

Comment: You don't need to put all the data in another table. MySQL Joins is the answer for your problem. The result of the select(with the data from these 3 tables) can be searched after using WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how your tables are connected because they don't have  very specific names but have you tried this?

```
SELECT * from table2
LEFT JOIN table3 on table2.AntennaNum = table3.AntennaNum
LEFT JOIN table4 on table3.LocationNum = table4.LocationNum
```

*PS. Next time when you ask a question please add what you tried and failed. Thank you!*

**Update:**

I tried to identify the foreign keys of your tables. Try this one:

```
SELECT * from table2
LEFT JOIN table3 on table2.AntennaNum = table3.UniqueId
LEFT JOIN table4 on table3.LocationNum = table4.UniqueId
```

Comment: I tried this SQL: UPDATE fccpool LatDec  INNER JOIN
       lotest
       ON fccpool.UniqueID = lotest.UniqueID AND fccpool.LocationNum = lotestLocationNum
    SET fccpool.LatDec = lotest.LatDec;

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere. I did a concat statment to add UniqueID and LocationNum together so I could only use one condition. however using the following stament my update has been going for 10+ minutes:                UPDATE
    table1 1,
    table2 2
SET
    1.FrequencyAssigned = 2.FrequencyAssigned
WHERE
    1.UniqueID = 2.UniqueID;

Comment: You need some special columns in your tables called `foreign keys` in order to 'connect' your tables. It's hard to identify them in your tables. Try the updated version of my post to see if you get any results